# how to output an objects keys when some key/value pairs have different keys but same values

Tags: javascript

I have the following object...

```
object = {
"A":["1","choiceONE"],
"B":["1","choiceTHREE"],
"C":["1","choiceONE"],
"D":["1","choiceONE"],
"E":["1","choiceTWO"],
"F":["4","choiceONE"],
"G":["4","choiceTHREE"],
"H":["4","choiceTHREE"]
}
```

I am trying to find a way to get the keys where the values of those keys are the same.

Desired Output:

```
[["A","C","D"], ["G","H"]]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for duplicate values?

Comment: Collect values in an object that uses "choiceX" as keys, then get its values: https://jsfiddle.net/537uLjdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need those with legnth > 1

```
const object = {
    "A":["1","choiceONE"],
    "B":["1","choiceTHREE"],
    "C":["1","choiceONE"],
    "D":["1","choiceONE"],
    "E":["1","choiceTWO"],
    "F":["4","choiceONE"],
    "G":["4","choiceTHREE"],
    "H":["4","choiceTHREE"]
}


function extrangeThing(target){
    let o={};
    for (const property in target) {
        const key=JSON.stringify(target[property]);
        if(o[key]) o[key].push(property);
        else o[key]=[property];
    }
    return Object.values(o).filter(x=>x.length>1);
}
```

Comment: Please do not post answers to gimme-the-code questions

Comment: ChrisG - thanks for trying - output is wrong.